# Custom SharePoint Alert message or Workflow to list column data from all items in one day

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow, custom-alert-templates, sharepoint-alerts

A request was received to send a daily email notification with custom text and to display the column data of a specific column from any/all files uploaded in that day.

Is this possible, without Visual Studio or Server or Central Admin access, but only with Site Admin access?

Draft Alert of Workflow Message Format Requested:

Text text text text:

//Insert List of [Single line of text column] that were uploaded that day

//Example:

Code 33657
Code 33455
Code 77845
Code 44456
Code 33678

Were uploaded today. Visit library to view.

Each Code xxxxx text column would be displayed for all files uploaded that day, compiled in a single daily auto email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That greatly depends on the version of SharePoint/SharePoint Designer. This is not possible with SPD 2010 workflows, but can be done with SPD 2013 or later, using the dictionary and HTTP web service actions. Not for the faint hearted.

Wonder Laura has a good tutorial here: https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/

In order to keep this manageable, you may want to create a view that is filtered to show only the items you want to include, then loop over all items in that view.

In SharePoint online, you would use Power Automate, which has its own set of tools to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!